# The recyclerView is not showing when I run the app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

the mock data in the layout section is showing alright. It is when I run the app no data is flowing into the recycler view. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at my code below.

activity_hourly_forecast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ui.HourlyForecastActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/hourlyListItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/hourly_list_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

hourly_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="hour"
        type="com.example.stormy.model.Hour"/>
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hourlyListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    tools:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(hour.time)}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="12 PM"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/timeLabel"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/partly_cloudy"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temperatureLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(hour.temperature)}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="100"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(hour.summary)}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="Partly cloudy"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

HourlyAdapter.java:

```
    package com.example.stormy.adapters;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.example.stormy.R;
    import com.example.stormy.databinding.HourlyListItemBinding;
    import com.example.stormy.model.Hour;

    import java.util.List;

    //manage the views from the hourly_list_item layout
    public class HourlyAdapter extends                   
RecyclerView.Adapter<HourlyAdapter.ViewHolder>{`

    private List<Hour> hours;
    Context context;

    public HourlyAdapter(List<Hour> hours, Context context) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HourlyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        HourlyListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.hourly_list_item,parent,
                false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Hour hour = hours.get(position);
        holder.hourlyListItemBinding.setHour(hour);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hours.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //binding variables
        //constructer to do view lookups for each subview
        public HourlyListItemBinding hourlyListItemBinding;
        public ViewHolder(HourlyListItemBinding hourlyLayoutBinding){
            super(hourlyLayoutBinding.getRoot());
            hourlyListItemBinding = hourlyLayoutBinding;
        }
    }
}
```

HourlyForecastActivity.java

```
package com.example.stormy.ui;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.stormy.R;
import com.example.stormy.adapters.HourlyAdapter;
import com.example.stormy.databinding.ActivityHourlyForecastBinding;
import com.example.stormy.model.Hour;
import    com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HourlyForecastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private HourlyAdapter adapter;
private ActivityHourlyForecastBinding binding;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding =    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_hourly_forecast);
    binding.hourlyListItems.setLayoutManager(new    LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new HourlyAdapter(getHourData(),this);
    binding.hourlyListItems.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private List<Hour> getHourData() {
    List<Hour> hours = new ArrayList<>();
    Hour hour = new Hour(1526508000, "Mostly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-day", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526511600, "Clear", 57.29, "clear-night", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526515200, "Clear", 57.29, "clear-day", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526518800, "Windy", 57.29, "wind", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526522400, "Snowy", 57.29, "snow", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526526000, "Raining", 57.29, "rain", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526529600, "Foggy", 57.29, "fog", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526533200, "Mostly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-night", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526536800, "Sleet", 57.29, "sleet", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526540400, "Cloudy", 57.29, "cloudy", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(152654400, "Mostly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-day", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526547600, "Partly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-night", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526551200, "Partly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-night", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    hour = new Hour(1526554800, "Partly Cloudy", 57.29, "partly-cloudy-night", "America/Los_Angeles");
    hours.add(hour);
    return hours;
}
```

}

The mock data in the layout is there, and I am setting the data statically but later on I'll utilize an API to set the data dynamically based on location. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are usinf Firebase realtime database?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is hard to find the issue with this amount of code. This code seems alright. Something might be wrong with your Activity. Would you mind sharing that?

Comment: @ChintanSoni just did that. I thought I had included all the code but it wasn't. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin No, I am not using any database currently, the data is defined in the getHourData() method in HourlyForecastActivity for the time being.

Comment: what do you mean by no data is flowing in recyclerview

Comment: how did you check that

Comment: also you have the text color as white as well as the recyclerview background is white. which doesn't makes sense, because then the text will not be visible.

Comment: @IsmailShaikh I ran the app on my virtual device and when I click on the button to navigate to the recycler view activity no data is showing there. it's basically a blank page.

Comment: @IsmailShaikh omg, can't believe this has been the error!!!! thank you so much for your help, that solved the problem. I changed the colors and it's ok now! GRACIAS!!

Comment: you are welcome. I'll add it as an answer. please mark it as accepted

Comment: sure! @IsmailShaikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your list item layout, you have the text color as white as well as the RecyclerView background is white. Because of that, the text will not be visible and you are getting a blank screen.